# Dealing with a webapp that's eating whitespace

Tags: pdf, unicode, text-editing, web-application

I'm filling out an application form for some funding, but the form eats whitespace - newlines are removed, and multiple spaces are reduced to one.
This is the resulting PDF:

[image]

It's my understanding that the judges get the same pdf - so it must been annoying to them as well.  Are there any suggestions for things I could try to 'add in' whitespace to make it easier for everybody to see?   My understanding is that the software is being used in a way it wasn't originally designed for.

Comment: If they remove spaces and newlines then they can remove other characters too, without knowing the exact form it's unlikely that we can help you? Have you tried it on another computer (windows or linux)? Your best bet is to ask the author / owner for formatting tips.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I've reworded in response to your comment.

Comment: Again, without knowing the software, it's pretty impossible to help you; maybe try tab, non-breaking space, line break (shift+enter) in windows...